# equal-if (jbob proof assistant)

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, programming

I'm trying to read through The Little Prover and the book introduces a language, ACL2, a Common Lisp derivative, for talking about proofs about programming languages.

The book introduces the following statement:

```
(if (if (equal a 't)
   (if 't
       a
       b)
   (equal 'or '(black coffee)))
c
c)
```

Where (if 't a b) is a, the if-true rule, and (if 'nil a b) is b, the if-false rule.

Now, the book also says we can simplify this statement by using the if-true rule.

```
(if (if (equal a 't)
   a
   (equal 'or '(black coffee)))
c
c)
```

The book then says:

> Does the if question (equal a 't) tell us anything about a?

And then answers:

> Yes, since a is in the if answer of the question (equal a 't), we know that a is equal to 't.

This deduction really confuses me! It seems to me that since (equal 'or '(black coffee)) is nil, we know the interior if statement is either 't because (equal a 't) is 't if a is 't and then the statement equals a, which we then know to be 't or the statement is 'nill because a is not 't. But, I don't see how we know a is 't.

The book then introduces this theorem:

```
(dethm equal-if (x y)
   (if (equal x y) (equal x y) 't))
```

Which confuses me even more.

Comment: If you know `(equal a 't)` is true, then you know $a={'t}$ and you can substitute `'t` for `a`. Similarly, if you know `(equal x y)` is true, then you can replace `(equal x y)` with `'t`. Presumably there is a theorem that says `(if x y y)` is the same as `y`.

Comment: The brackets in your first code quote don't balance (there should probably be a bracket after "b"). "dethm" in the last  quote should probably read "defthm".  The text you quote doesn't make much sense to me -  have you quoted it accurately? The theorem is fine though: (if 't p q) evaluates to p and (if nil p q) evaluates to q, so (if p p 't) will always evaluate to 't if p is either 't or nil, whilch will be the case if p is the equality test (equal x y).